# Hololens - create app on desktop

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens

I can't figure out the wording to research the following idea.

With the Holograms app, I can set the hologram and see the other apps front window or use web browser at the same time.

How can I create an app that does not occupy the whole system but only run on the desktop with browser and others?

EDIT: I am trying to run an hologram within the shell.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/hololens_shell_overview

Mostly, this is for 2D apps, but the Holograms app runs 3D holograms, so is it possible to duplicate this?

Comment: http://forums.hololens.com/discussion/374/how-to-make-an-inactive-app-appear-as-3d-widget-in-the-shell-instead-of-a-flat-quad

seems what I need is not yet available...

Answer (score 2):

3D Hololens apps do not currently support running side by side with other applications. As of the May release you are able to run multiple "flat apps" (UWP apps) side by side:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/holographic/release_notes_-_may_2016

Currently there has not been any announcement about running multiple 3d apps side by side.  I optimistically hope that this is coming in a future OS release.

Comment: Yes, this is what I said in the comment under the OP. Only flat tile.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you are interested in creating an application for the Hololens that rather than having it "appear in the world around you", would run in a Window (Desktop) that would appear in the spatial world (like Edge). If this is correct, any UWP application can run Windowed and be placed in you virtual space. You don't need a specific Hololens project for that. If however you want to pull in spatial data, you would need to wire-up the required events so that spatial data callbacks handle the incoming data. I'm not 100% sure Unity is a best fit for this problem (at least currently) since they are focusing attention on Spatial hologram applications rather than desktop UWP applications that consume spatial data.

Comment: I guess that' d be the second case where an hologram is placed and "activated" while you can see other windowed app like edge. Think of it like the weight lifter being positioned and animated in a corner of the room while also browsing the web. I am interested in how to create that hologram that sits and acts in the initial space of Hololens. Hopefully i am clear enough. Maybe i'll add a pic when i got a chance.

Comment: Are you referring to the fact that on the emulator your app seems to move to a different space other than the room? If so it is important to understand that the black that you see on the emulator while running your app, will be replace with all open holograms, plus yours, plus desktop apps windows, as well as the rest of the room on the actual device. So even though it seems like your holograms aren't merged with other apps on the emulator, in reality they will be. in other words it will seem combined on the actual device.

Comment: Well I figured out that what I was trying to do is not available from the public API. I guess the Holograms app developer had access to some extra features.

Comment: It seems I had confused flat Apps running side by side. @Cameron Vetter's answered clarified that and I tested it to confirm he is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, it is worth stating that a single 3D app (ie Unity developed) takes over the whole HoloLens device and experience. If you bloom (windows key in emulator) you can change to the UWP app view but you can't see other apps at the same time.